# barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE) weird deadlock in kernel's local array when reduction

Tags: opencl, intel, barrier, spir

The code run well by clCreateProgramWithSource, **BUT** dealock by clCreateProgramWithBinary. 
The size of work group is (8,8), I reproduce the deadlock on Intel Graphics win8.1+ HD4600/530 and win10+HD630.

```
local int SumAlpha[16*16/4];
int index = 1*get_local_id(0)+ 16/2*get_local_id(1);
......
SumAlpha[index] = sum_alpha;

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
// do reduction in shared mem
for(int i = (16*16/8); i > 0; i >>= 1) 
{
    if(index < i) 
    {
        SumAlpha[index] += SumAlpha[index + i]; 
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // unroll loop show deadlock when i==8
}
```

the cmd which create spir is

```
"..\vendors\OpenCL\Intel\bin\ioc32.exe -cmd=build -input="xxx" -device=gpu -spir32="FileName%" -bo="-cl-std=CL1.2 -I %ProjetcDir%\cl"
```

And I tried '-cl-opt-disable', same deadlock.
I tried below equivalence, also deadlock.

```
a = SumAlpha[index];
b = SumAlpha[index + i];
SumAlpha[index] = a+ b;
```

I can use instruction dot to avoid reduction, while I want to know more.
Did I miss something? Or is there any way to dump out the gen assembly of both way to compare their difference? Greatly Thanks.

Comment: If you compile with clCreateProgramFromSource then get the binary using the OpenCL API (clGetProgramInfo or something like that), and then use that with clCreateProgramWithBinary, does that work?

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue with a CPU device, you could use the `-asm[=<file_path>]` option to generate assembler code.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR/issues/3 ? It might be worth using the reference SPIR compiler instead of Intels, just in case they didn't fix that issue. Alternatively, try disassembling the SPIR to see if the barrier bug is there.